# Overflow content of bootstrap Accordion

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, mdbootstrap

I would like to have scrollable content within a bootstrap accordion, but can't get it to work.
Closest I have got was using flex-column and overflow-hidden on parents and overflow-auto on the content elements like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header></header>
    <main>
    <script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/3.11.0/mdb.min.js"
></script>


<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
<!-- MDB -->
<link
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/3.11.0/mdb.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
    <div class="accordion vh-100 d-flex flex-column" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item overflow-hidden d-flex flex-column">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button
        class="accordion-button"
        type="button"
        data-mdb-toggle="collapse"
        data-mdb-target="#collapseOne"
        aria-expanded="true"
        aria-controls="collapseOne"
      >
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show  overflow-auto" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-mdb-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body overflow-auto">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default,
        until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each
        element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or
        overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML
        can go within the <strong>.accordion-body</strong>, though the transition does
        limit overflow.
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default,
        until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each
        element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or
        overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML
        can go within the <strong>.accordion-body</strong>, though the transition does
        limit overflow.
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default,
        until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each
        element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or
        overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML
        can go within the <strong>.accordion-body</strong>, though the transition does
        limit overflow.
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default,
        until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each
        element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or
        overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML
        can go within the <strong>.accordion-body</strong>, though the transition does
        limit overflow.
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default,
        until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each
        element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or
        overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML
        can go within the <strong>.accordion-body</strong>, though the transition does
        limit overflow.
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default,
        until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each
        element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or
        overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML
        can go within the <strong>.accordion-body</strong>, though the transition does
        limit overflow.
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default,
        until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each
        element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or
        overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML
        can go within the <strong>.accordion-body</strong>, though the transition does
        limit overflow.
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default,
        until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each
        element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or
        overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML
        can go within the <strong>.accordion-body</strong>, though the transition does
        limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item overflow-hidden d-flex flex-column">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button
        class="accordion-button collapsed"
        type="button"
        data-mdb-toggle="collapse"
        data-mdb-target="#collapseTwo"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-controls="collapseTwo"
      >
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse overflow-auto" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-mdb-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body overflow-auto">
      <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default,
        until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each
        element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or
        overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML
        can go within the <strong>.accordion-body</strong>, though the transition does
        limit overflow.
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default,
        until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each
        element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or
        overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML
        can go within the <strong>.accordion-body</strong>, though the transition does
        limit overflow.
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default,
        until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each
        element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or
        overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML
        can go within the <strong>.accordion-body</strong>, though the transition does
        limit overflow.
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default,
        until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each
        element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or
        overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML
        can go within the <strong>.accordion-body</strong>, though the transition does
        limit overflow.
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default,
        until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each
        element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or
        overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML
        can go within the <strong>.accordion-body</strong>, though the transition does
        limit overflow.
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default,
        until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each
        element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or
        overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML
        can go within the <strong>.accordion-body</strong>, though the transition does
        limit overflow.
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default,
        until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each
        element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or
        overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML
        can go within the <strong>.accordion-body</strong>, though the transition does
        limit overflow.
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default,
        until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each
        element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or
        overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML
        can go within the <strong>.accordion-body</strong>, though the transition does
        limit overflow.
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by
        default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to
        style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the
        showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS
        or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any
        HTML can go within the <strong>.accordion-body</strong>, though the transition
        does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 
  </div>
</div>



    </main>
    <footer></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

But there because of the overflow-hidden on the accordion-item element, when you open a page on it, the other elements get shrunk.